# Wrong number being output from if loops

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, double, cout

I have to calculate taxable income and for some reason when I input income as 5000 and filing m for married, it is giving me a slightly wrong number. Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double calcTax = 0;
    double income = 0;
    char choice;
    do {
        //Prompt user for income

        cout << "Please enter in your taxable income.\nThis must be a positve number:" << endl;
        cin >> income;
        while (income < 0)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a positive value" << endl;
            cin >> income;
        }

        //Ask if user is filing as single or married. Continue until correct input is received
        char status;
        cout << "Please enter an 'm' if married and filing jointly or an 's' if single and filing alone:" << endl;
        cin >> status;
        while ((status != 'm') && (status != 's'))
        {
            cout << "You have pressed an incorrect key. Please enter an 'm' if married and filing jointly or an 's' if single and fiing alone:" << endl;
            cin >> status;
        }
        double sBase1 = 863,
            sBase2 = 2588,
            sBase3 = 4313,
            mBase1 = 1726,
            mBase2 = 5176,
            mBase3 = 8626;

        double sAdd2 = 25,
            sAdd3 = 85,
            sAdd4 = 181,
            mAdd2 = 40,
            mAdd3 = 175,
            mAdd4 = 390;

        double taxRate1 = 0.023,
            taxRate2 = 0.033,
            taxRate3 = 0.052,
            taxRate4 = 0.075;



        //Calculate tax if user is single, based on income tier
        if (status == 's')
        {
            if (income <= sBase1)
            {
                calcTax = income * taxRate1;
            }
            if (sBase1 < income <= sBase2)
            {
                calcTax = ((income - sBase1)) * taxRate2 + sAdd2;
            }
            if (sBase2 < income <= sBase3)
            {
                calcTax = ((income - sBase2) * taxRate3) + sAdd3;
            }
            if (sBase3 < income)
            {
                calcTax = ((income - sBase3) * taxRate4) + sAdd4;
            }
        }

        //Calculate tax if user is married, based on income tier
        if (status == 'm')
        {
            if (income <= mBase1)
            {
                calcTax = income * taxRate1;
            }
            if (mBase1 < income <= mBase2)
            {
                calcTax = ((income - mBase1)) * taxRate2 + mAdd2;
            }
            if (mBase2 < income <= mBase3)
            {
                calcTax = ((income - mBase2) * taxRate3) + mAdd3;
            }
            if (mBase3 < income)
            {
                calcTax = ((income - mBase3) * taxRate4) + mAdd4;
            }

        }

        //Display user's tax
        cout << "$" << fixed << setprecision(2) << calcTax << endl;

        //Ask if user would like to calculate another tax
        //If so, repeat until done
        char response;
        cout << "Would you like to perform another tax calculation (y or n)?:" << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        while (choice != 'n' && choice != 'y')
        {
            cout << "Please enter y or n" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
        }


    } while (choice == 'y');
    return 0;
}
```

5000 and married should return 148.04 but instead I get 165.85. Can anyone help point out what is going wrong??

Comment: I think you would benefit from using an IDE with a debugger. I suggest downloading Visual Studio or Eclipse. If you have never debugged code, look for a short YouTube video on how to debug in your IDE of choice.

Comment: Why don't you provide a formula with which you are supposed to calculate your code? That way we can  compare your formula to how your program computes th tax and track down the bug.

Comment: plukich, I am already using Visual Studio.

Comment: If you don't want to or can't use a debugger, the poor man's way is to add some "cout" statements to print out your variables' values throughout your code.  Eg: do a cout << calcTax right before your line that attempts to format the decimal.as currency. Does the value look correct there? If so then your currency formatting is the culprit. If the value is wrong there, then keep working back up through your code to find the point where the value gets set incorrectly

Comment: if is not a loop!

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the if loops, because I have used breaks after each statement and it seems like after the initial calculation it may be going back through the loop or something but I'm not quite sure why or how to fix it.

Comment: @riahtron3000 can you right click the line that says if (status=='m') and Set Breakpoint, then Start your program in Debug and F10 (Step) your way through it, one line at a time until you find the issue

Comment: For single, if income is under 863 multiply by 0.023. If income is between 864-2588 subtract 863 from income, multiply by .033 and add 25. Between 2589-4313 subtract 2588, multiply by .052, add 85. Over 4313, subtract 4313 multiply by .075 and add 181

Comment: For married, if income is up to 1726, multiply by .023. If between 1727-5176 subtract 1726m multiply by .033 and add 40. If between 5177-8626 subtract 5176 multiply by .052 and add 175. if over 8626 subtract 8626, multiply by .075 and add 390

Comment: Here's a video of debugging c++ in VS. highly suggest you try this. https://youtu.be/arFGdbRfQ3o

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, I fixed it. Instead of all if statements I used if, else if statements. And instead of starting from lowest and going up I started with the highest tier going down so as to prevent double processing my income.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if-clauses are the cause for that behaviour. Writing something like `if (mBase1 < income <= mBase2)` does not have the same mathematical meaning in C++, since the compiler only compares two values at a time (if I am not mistaken).

So write:

`if (mBase1 < income && income <= mBase2)` instead to make sure, that he should compare both statements **and** make sure both are valid.

Replacing the line

`if (mBase2 < income <= mBase3)`

with `if (mBase2 < income && income <= mBase3)`

already did the trick in giving you the right prompt for your given example (5000 and "m). Without that, the compiler thinks something like:

> mBase2 < income ? That is false, but income <= mBase3 ? That is true, lets enter this if-clause

and thus overwriting your `calcTax`-value

Answer (score 0):

```
You cannot compare two conditions at a time using if statement 
if(a<b<c) is similar to 
if( (a<b) || (b<c)  )
so in your program you should use && instead of comparing straight away
```

example :

```
  #include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    if (5 < 6)
    {
        printf("5 is less than 6\n");
    }
    if (90 >6 )
    {
        printf("6 is less than 90\n");
    }
    if (5 < 6 <90) // here only half of the condition checking takes place ..till (5<6) and (6<90 )is not verified
    {
        printf("5 is less than 6 and 6 is less than 90");
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;

}



so change your code to--->


 #include < iostream>

 #include < iomanip>

 #include < cmath>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
{

   double calcTax = 0;

 double income = 0;

    char choice;
    do {
        //Prompt user for income

        cout << "Please enter in your taxable income.\nThis must be a positve number:" << endl;
        cin >> income;
        while (income < 0)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a positive value" << endl;
            cin >> income;
        }

        //Ask if user is filing as single or married. Continue until correct input is received
        char status;
        cout << "Please enter an 'm' if married and filing jointly or an 's' if single and filing alone:" << endl;
        cin >> status;
        while ((status != 'm') && (status != 's'))
        {
            cout << "You have pressed an incorrect key. Please enter an 'm' if married and filing jointly or an 's' if single and fiing alone:" << endl;
            cin >> status;
        }
        double sBase1 = 863,
            sBase2 = 2588,
            sBase3 = 4313,
            mBase1 = 1726,
            mBase2 = 5176,
            mBase3 = 8626;

        double sAdd2 = 25,
            sAdd3 = 85,
            sAdd4 = 181,
            mAdd2 = 40,
            mAdd3 = 175,
            mAdd4 = 390;

        double taxRate1 = 0.023,
            taxRate2 = 0.033,
            taxRate3 = 0.052,
            taxRate4 = 0.075;



        //Calculate tax if user is single, based on income tier
        if (status == 's')
        {
            if (income <= sBase1)
            {
                calcTax = income * taxRate1;
            }
            if (sBase1 < income <= sBase2)
            {
                calcTax = ((income - sBase1)) * taxRate2 + sAdd2;
            }
            if (sBase2 < income <= sBase3)
            {
                calcTax = ((income - sBase2) * taxRate3) + sAdd3;
            }
            if (sBase3 < income)
            {
                calcTax = ((income - sBase3) * taxRate4) + sAdd4;
            }
        }

        //Calculate tax if user is married, based on income tier
        if (status == 'm')
        {
            if (income <= mBase1)
            {
                calcTax = income * taxRate1;
            }
            if ((mBase1 < income) && (income <= mBase2))
            {
                calcTax = (((income - mBase1) * taxRate2) + mAdd2);
            }
            if ((mBase2 < income) &&(income <= mBase3))
            {
                calcTax = ((income - mBase2) * taxRate3) + mAdd3;
            }
            if (mBase3 < income)
            {
                calcTax = ((income - mBase3) * taxRate4) + mAdd4;
            }

        }

        //Display user's tax
        cout << "$" << fixed << setprecision(2) << calcTax << endl;

        //Ask if user would like to calculate another tax
        //If so, repeat until done
        char response;
        cout << "Would you like to perform another tax calculation (y or n)?:" << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        while (choice != 'n' && choice != 'y')
        {
            cout << "Please enter y or n" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
        }


    } while (choice == 'y');
    return 0;
}
```